# How can I make tikzpicture flow smoothly around text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

I have a problem when I use `tikzpicture` and `wrapfigure`. The main issue is that when using the third parameter, the "distance" becomes arbitary. For example, I am using `9cm` but what is the correct way to do it? Because, currently, the text looks out of place and not aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

Whenever we deal with integration, we come across the constant of integration $C$. Suppose we have the following graph of $ f(x) = \sin x$. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{9cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $f(x)$
]
\addplot{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

The primary reason for doing integration is to be able to solve differential equations.

\begin{quote}
    some random text goes here and other cool stuff.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of using `9cm`, use `0pt`, then the natural width of the `wrapfigure` will be used to align the surrounding text. It may also look weird to have an indent in the first line, so adding `\noindent The primary...` makes it look a little less weird.

Comment: If your figure is more than 3/4 of the text width I would not wrap the text around it but center it and let it float. For smaller figures Werner's comment is spot on. You can shrink the plot for example by using the `width=6cm` argument to the axis environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! If one of you would like to post one as an answer so I can accept it, that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `9cm`, use `0pt`, then the natural width of the `wrapfigure` will be used to align the surrounding text. It may also look weird to have an indent in the first line, so adding `\noindent The primary...` makes it look a little less weird.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}

\begin{document}

Whenever we deal with integration, we come across the constant of integration $C$. Suppose we have the following graph of $ f(x) = \sin x$. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $f(x)$
]
\addplot{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent The primary reason for doing integration is to be able to solve differential equations.

\begin{quote}
    some random text goes here and other cool stuff.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```